# How to integrate $f(x)^n$

Tags: integration

$$\int({F(x)})^n dx$$

$F(x)$ is arbitrary

$n$ is a positive integer

Sorry this may be an easy question but It's hard to look on the web for  such specific questions as they're hardly asked by anyone

Comment: There is probably no answer to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration is not so straightforward as differentiation. We can have continuous, and even differentiable, functions which have no analytic antiderivative. This integral has no analytic solution except for a set of specific $F(x)$'s. $F(x)=x^p$ for any $p\in\mathbb{R}$ is an example of a function where you can find an antiderivative for $F(x)^n$, but this will not work for arbitrary $F(x)$.

Comment: thanks for your answer